# Quantifiable Reasons to Upgrade to VS2015

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2015

We are currently running Visual Studio 2010 for our production software. Our team would like to upgrade to VS2015 and eventually use it for production. With this, we need to do some convincing with features other than "that's nice to have." Our products are C\C++ based so many of the new "Wow" features will not be applicable to us. Please provide some compelling reasons to make this upgrade happen. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Hmm, everybody is ignoring that the C++ language changed a *lot*?  C++11 and C++14 and what's planned for C++17 are **not** minor changes.  When you're trapped in a stagnant place then [this SE service](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/) is where you look for a solution.

Comment: @Nole Fan 81 No feedback from you whatsoever. Did the answer help you in any way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer will by no means try to be a complete comparision
of VS2010 vs VS2015 for C/C++ development. I will, however, 
list several advantages of VS2015 that (in my opinion) justify 
the transition:

1. C++ compiler that ships with VS2015 supports all features of C++11
   and almost all features of C++14:

   http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support
2. Intellisense for C++ is VASTLY SUPERIOR in VS2015, which results 
   in a significant productivity boost!
3. Git integration in VS2015! You can use git directly from the IDE!
4. Advanced refactoring facilities like Quick Actions provide additional
   productivity boost.
5. Support for MS unit testing framework (Native Unit Tests)

I know that some people will not agree but I also think that the change in
user interface is an improvement (or maybe I just really like the dark theme
that comes with VS2012+ versions).